# Which sharepoint exam is the best to begin: 70-488 or 70-489?

Tags: certification, exam

Which sharepoint exam is the best to begin: 70-488 or 70-489 ? And which one is the easy one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can reference to this page for the full SharePoint developer certification path: [here](https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx).

As you can see 488 is the basic exam and 489 is the advanced one, so (hopefully) you need to take them in that order.

Also notice that if you want the MCSD certification you will have to take the other two exams.

[image]
(screen taken as of 03/07/2014)

Comment: (had the question open from 2 hours and didn't see the new answer posted prompt. I will leave this here for now).

Comment: +1 For including a nice picture :).

Comment: @CameronVerhelst I had forgot the most important thing of all.... The [mighty freehand circle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19775/171199).

Comment: Haha, I didn't realise it was an actual meme until now, thx for that!

Comment: I took the 489 exam first, it was perhaps the hardest MS certification exam I have ever taken.

Answer (score 4):

488 is the core one and 489 the advanced one, so you should normally start with 488 that is the easier cert.

I have passed both.

More information about 70-488: https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?id=70-488

and 70-489: https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?id=70-489

Comment: can you point reference material for 488 please. Like the Microsoft MVA, etc?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/exam.aspx?id=70-488